# Long queries execution time when using Server Explorer with Azure Storage

Tags: logging, azure, sitecore, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

We have a web portal based on Sitecore CMS hosted on Azure. In such configuration Sitecore writes logs to Azure Storage instead of plain txt files which is fine, but unfortunately it proved to be really inefficient for us.

For browsing logs we use Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2012 and invoking one query (for example to fetch logs from just current day) takes 10-15 minutes before we receive any results.

Not only it's frustrating, but it will also become unacceptable as soon as we deploy our solution to production servers - please consider searching for production bugs when browsing logs table requires 15 minutes for simple fetching the data :)

I'd like to know if there is an easy solution to this problem, maybe you have some hints on it - there can be some connection flaws or maybe we're able to invoke queries that take less time? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you creating your query using Timestamp attribute? You **must** include PartitionKey in your query to avoid full table scan.

Comment: You're right - when I enter PartitionKey it's much quicker, however I'm not sure how PartitionKey is generated - it seems to change every few minutes and I have to see the full results to find out "current" PartitionKey. I'm new to this project so please correct me if I'm thinking in a wrong way.

Comment: Are you trying to look at standard Windows Azure Diagnostics data? If that's the case, then this blog post might help: gauravmantri.com/2012/02/17/effective-way-of-fetching-diagnostics-data-from-windows-azure-diagnostics-table-hint-use-partitionkey/

Comment: It's WADLogsTable indeed, thanks Gaurav - I'll take a look at this article.